# Команды с аргументами telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Я пишу своего первого бота на [pytelebotapi](/questions/tagged/pytelebotapi) и я хочу сделать текст команду с аргументами, чтобы когда я написал `привет, (имя бота)` и он отреагировал на мое сообщения и приветствовал меня, а если я не угадывал имя, он говорил что его не так зовут, но есть проблема, у меня условие не работает потому что `привет,` и `имя бота` идёт как один текст и не имеет аргумента, можете решить проблему?

Прилагаю код:

```py
import telebot
import config
from script import *

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


def argument(arg):
    return arg.split()[1:]

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def start_save(message):
     if message.text.lower() == "привет,":
        namebot = argument(message.text)
        if namebot[1] == "Телебот":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет мой хозяин!")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Прости, если забыл, то меня не" + message_text + ", попробуй мое имя спомнить")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def welcome(message):
    if 'привет,' in message.text.lower():
        if message.text.split(',')[1].replace(' ', '') == 'телебот':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет бро!')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Меня зовут не так')
```

но мне кажется, что проще сделать "нужное" приветствие через id пользователя:

```
def welcome(message):
    adm = [123]  # id пользователей
    if 'привет' in message.text.lower() and message.chat.id in adm:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет бро!')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мы знакомы?')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое , вы очень помогли.

Comment: Если ответ является решением Вашего вопроса, пожалуйста отметьте его (галочка около ответа) это поможет другим пользователями. Так же Вы можете за него проголосовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def user_text(message):
    print(Back.LIGHTBLACK_EX, "Пользователь ", message.from_user.username, "вызвал:", message.text)
    if message.text == 'Наш сайт':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "google.com")
    elif message.text == 'Помощь':
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "тг админа")
    else:
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "знакомы?")
```

Вот я скопировал из своего кода и я думаю, что этот вариант лучше. Я не понимаю зачем в `name` бот суёшь полученный текст лучше сделать так.